# Reinstall WordPress from zero

Tags: installation

So, i'm a member of a voluntary team in my university and we're having a wordpress website. I'm the only one who knows how to handle it so i'm responsible for everything about it. The problem is that we're having some problems with it (like not allowing to upload anything, except if i manually upload it from FileZilla) and i'd like to delete this particular version and clean install a new one. The problem is I haven't done this before so i'd like someone to verify that the steps i'm going to make are correct:

1. Delete wordpress database from Phpmyadmin
2. Delete everything regarding wordpress inside public_html folder from FileZilla
3. Create a new database,
4. Install a new WordPress version in public_html folder

Are those the exact steps?

Comment: so, you want to delete everything(db, uploaded files, themes, plugins and load some other version of wordpress)?

Comment: Yeah, I want to install a new wordpress version from zero. Like there was never there before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right. Steps need to do:

1. Delete the `db` related to your WordPress installation( or you can just emty your `db` without deleting it. This option will save several minutes of your time to not creating another `database` )
2. Delete all files related to your installation
3. Upload another version of website, unzip it( if it has archived ) and call your website url from browser
4. You'll see fresh WordPress installation page:

[image][image]

After filling required fields, you'll got fresh WordPress installation.